# How to detect area click into Image in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with detect area click into an image.

I have the images below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZmq0.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sb6Va.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMwpy.jpg

How can I detect when touching into the yellow area?

Comment: you have to make slicing of whole image into different yellow area portion, then you can access particular area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be easy. You don't need to slice it.

The thing you have to do is

1. Click event.
2. Get the position where you clicked.
3. Get the colour of the position.
4. Check if the colour is yellow or not.
5. Do what you want when it is yellow.

It seems like the yellow is not just one yellow colour. So, What you can do is have a range of the yellow colour and compare all the possible yellow colours.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            if(getColourOfThePixel(x, y)){
                // DO SOMETHING
            }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public boolean getColourOfThePixel(float x, float y){
    int colorXY = mBitmap.getPixel(rangeX, rangeY);

    int r = Color.red(colorXY);
    int g = Color.green(colorXY);
    int b = Color.blue(colorXY);

    if (isYellow(r, g, b)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean isYellow(int r, int g, int b){
    // CHECK THE RANGE OF YELLOW COLOUR
}
```

To make it sure, you'd better have +-x, y ranges(like a square, maybe +-20pixel) because checking only one pixel may not work sometimes. So, if the square has a yellow colour, the event you wanna implement would work out.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Yes, thank you!. You're right, but I can't find the best way to check it's yellow color in the images. Do you have any the best way to help me with this problem?

Comment: Keep testing and figure it out. I guess you can do it with one colour, instead, with a bigger square would work better. If one colour seems not enough then, try with two or three colours, It would be alright. If it becomes slow, then, you don't really need to check all the pixels but every 3 pixels would be fine and 3times faster. If it was helpful. Please upvote and choose.